# Automatically post/share to group as a page/from a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups, automation

Is there any way to automatically share posts from your own Facebook page to your own Facebook group, with the post showing that it came from the page?
I tried several automation tools, but the only thing they let me do is copying the page posts' content and posting it to the group from my personal profile. What I'm looking to do, though, is to either make the group post acting as the page, or to share (not copy/paste) the page's post into the group so it will link to the page. Posting only the "First Action Link" also doesn't help.